# Power BI - bar chart sorting

Tags: powerbi

I am having a problem sorting my bar graph in date order (sendtime column) for my mailing data...

```
Axis: Campaign Title
Legend: Blank
Value: Total Sent, Total Opened, Totel Links Clicked
```

I have tried to add this to the Axis which allows me to order by "Campaign Title and sendtime" which still sorts them alphabetically and if i add to the values section it simply does a count.

I am using a slicer to control the various chart (and other pie chart) however i would like them ordered by when they were sent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a strange answer to come across but in the end I had to use a different date set, add it to the relative date filter option and then order.

Apologies if anyone has read this and wasted some trying to find a solution.